# Javascript - Remove references to my object from external arrays

Tags: javascript, null, dereference

I have a problem with dereferencing a Javascript object and setting it to NULL.

Here, I have a Folder implementation that supports recursive subdirectory removal.  Please see my comments to understand my dilemma.

```
function Folder(name, DOM_rows) {
    this.name = name;
    this.files = [].concat(DOM_rows);
    this.subdirs = [];
}

Folder.prototype.AddDir(name, DOM_rows) {
   this.subdirs.push(new Folder(name, DOM_rows));
}

Folder.prototype.RemoveDir(folder) {
   var stack = [folder];
   while(stack.length > 0) {
      var cur = stack.pop();
      // do a post-order depth-first traversal, so dig to the deepest subdir:
      if(cur.subdirs.length > 0) {
          while(cur.subdirs.length > 0) { stack.push(cur.subdirs.pop()); }
      } else {
          // arrived at a leaf-level:
          cur.files = null;
          // now how do I delete cur from it's parent's subdirs array?
          // the only way I know how is to keep a "cur.parentDir" reference,
          // then find parent.subdirs[ index of cur ] and slice it out.
          // How can I do the JS-equivalent of *cur = NULL?
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using recursion for `RemoveDir`? Is there any additional processing not shown in sample that needs to be performed on files or folders when they're deleted?

Comment: @outis: I just prefer iterative over recursive.  It might be more space-effective to do it recursively in some cases, but I know that the breadth (number of subdirs at each level) will be small relative to the depth.  And actually, my app isn't about folders and files, but it has the same structure.  There are more properties to my "Folder" object that need to be processed and removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you don't have as big a problem as you suspect, since all subdirectories but `folder` in your `RemoveDir` will be deleted from their parent's `subdir` by the `stack.push(cur.subdirs.pop());` line

To find a subdirectory in a parent, you could make use an object-as-dictionary rather than an array for `subdirs`:

```
function Folder(name, DOM_rows, parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.files = [].concat(DOM_rows);
    this.subdirs = {};
    this.subdirCount = 0;
}

Folder.prototype.AddDir = function (name, DOM_rows) {
    if (this.subdirs[name]) {
        return null;
    }
    ++this.subdirCount;
    return this.subdirs[name] = new Folder(name, DOM_rows, this);
}
```

Given a folder, you can remove the folder from the parent with:

```
delete folder.parent.subdirs[folder.name];
```

Here's a preorder version:

```
Folder.prototype.RemoveDir = function (folder) {
  if (this.subdirs[folder.name] === folder) {
      var stack = [folder];
      while(stack.length > 0) {
          var cur = stack.pop();
          // pre-order
          delete cur.files;
          // if there's other processing to be done, now's the time to do it
          for (subdir in cur.subdirs) {
              stack.push(cur.subdirs[subdir]);
              delete cur.subdirs[subdir];
          }
          // it's unnecessary to set subdir count, since 'cur' has been deleted
          //cur.subdirCount = 0;
      }
      delete this.subdirs[folder.name];
      --this.subdirCount;
  }
}
```

And the recursive post-order version:

```
Folder.prototype.RemoveChildren = function () {
    for (subdir in this.subdirs) {
        this.RemoveDir(this.subdirs[subdir]);
    }
}

Folder.prototype.RemoveDir = function (folder) {
    if (this.subdirs[folder.name] === folder) {
        folder.RemoveChildren();
        folder.files = [];
        delete this.subdirs[folder.name];
        --this.subdirCount;
    }
}
```

And the iterative post-order version:

```
Array.prototype.top = function () { return this[this.length-1]; }

Folder.prototype.RemoveDir = function (folder) {
  if (this.subdirs[folder.name] === folder) {
      var stack = [folder];
      while(stack.length > 0) {
          var cur = stack.top();
          if (cur.subdirCount > 0) {
              for (subdir in cur.subdirs) {
                  stack.push(cur.subdirs[subdir]);
                  delete cur.subdirs[subdir];
              }
              cur.subdirCount = 0;
          } else {
              stack.pop();
              delete cur.files;
              // other post-order processing
          }
      }
      delete this.subdirs[folder.name];
  }
}
```

Though, unless you need to take additional steps when processing deleted files & folders, a simple:

```
Folder.prototype.RemoveDir = function (folder) {
  if (this.subdirs[folder.name] === folder) {
    delete this.subdirs[folder.name];
  }
}
```

should suffice.

Comment: Thanks outis - You went to town on this - and +1 for the .top() prototype.  I need to release references to DOM elements, so I can't just delete the reference to the folder, lest I risk memory leaks in IE.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is javascript is passed by value, so "*cur=NULL" is not possible. You basically have the following options here

- use parentID as you suggested
- if your Folder hierarchy has a well-known root, browse from that root to find the parent object
- use something like DOM removeChild (which is called on parent), instead of removeNode (which is called on the node itself).

Comment: Do you mean passed-by-reference?

Comment: To expand: Javascript is pass-by-value, but objects are stored by reference. It's sometimes called "pass by reference value". This is why the affect of `function foo(obj) {obj.qux = 1;}` is visible outside a call to `foo`, but not `function bar(obj) {obj = {qux: 1};}`.

Comment: @outis: Agree, only primitive arguments (`string`, `number`, `boolean`, `null` and `undefined`) are passed "by value", objects are passed "by reference" (or as you said, the reference is passed as value :).

Comment: I really really wish we had pass by reference reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do the same thing today.
I've worked around it by storing the object's index as a property of the object itself.

When you add it:

```
myObj.ID = myArr.push(myObj);
```

So to remove it you

```
myArr[myObj.ID] = null;
```

I guess you solved it by now, but you could do almost the same; and it's simpler than using objects.